# Bash Associative Array from String?

Tags: bash, associative-array

A command emits the string: "[abc]=kjlkjkl [def]=yutuiu [ghi]=jljlkj"

I want to load a bash associative array using these key|value pairs, but the result I'm getting is a single row array where the key is formed of the first pair `[abc]=kjlkjkl` and the value is the whole of the rest of the string, so: `declare -p arr` returns  `declare -A arr["[abc]=kjlkjkl"]="[def]=yutuiu [ghi]=jljlkj"`

This is what I am doing at the moment. Where am I going wrong please?

```
declare -A arr=()
while read -r a b; do
    arr["$a"]="$b"
done < <(command that outputs the string "[abc]=kjlkjkl [def]=yutuiu [ghi]=jljlkj")
```

Comment: Are the quotation marks part of the string?

Comment: are there really `[]` chars in the output you are passing in? I don't think that is helping. Also, `while read IFS="=" -r a b ...` might help.

Comment: Thank you both. The quotation marks are showing the string boundaries. There are none in the string itself. And, yes, there are `[]` in the string, but I am going to see if I can get output a different way to avoid them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse it: split the string on spaces, split each key-value pair on the equals sign, and get rid of the brackets.

Here's one way, using `tr` to replace the spaces with newlines, then `tr` again to remove all brackets (including any that occur in a value), then `IFS="="` to split the key-value pairs.  I'm sure this could be done more effectively, like with AWK or Perl, but I don't know how.

```
declare -A arr=()
while IFS="=" read -r a b; do
    arr["$a"]="$b"
done < <(
    echo "[abc]=kjlkjkl [def]=yutuiu [ghi]=jljlkj" |
        tr ' ' '\n' |
        tr -d '[]'
    )

echo "${arr[def]}"  # -> yutuiu
```

See [Cyrus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64947478/4518341) for another take on this, with the space and equals steps combined.

Comment: Thanks. As I've noted in @KamilCuk's answer, I can get the data pairs without `[]` and separated by spaces so I can trim this down to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Append this to your command which outputs the string:

```
| tr ' =' '\n ' | tr -d '[]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "eval declare" trick - but be sure your input is clean.

```
#! /bin/bash
s='[abc]=kjlkjkl [def]=yutuiu [ghi]=jljlkj'
eval declare -A arr=("$s")
echo ${arr[def]}  # yutuiu
```

If the input is insecure, don't use it. Imagine (don't try) what would happen if

```
s='); rm -rf / #'
```

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" good™ solution would be to write your own parser and tokenize the input. For example read the input char by char, handle `[` and `]` and `=` and space and optionally quoting. After parsing the string, assign the output to an associative array.

A simple way could be:

```
echo "[abc]=kjlkjkl [def]=yutuiu [ghi]=jljlkj" |
xargs -n1 |
{
declare -A arr;
while IFS= read -r line; do
   if [[ "$line" =~ ^\[([a-z]*)\]=([a-z]*)$ ]]; then
       arr[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
   fi
done
declare -p arr
}
```

outputs:

```
declare -A arr=([abc]="kjlkjkl" [ghi]="jljlkj" [def]="yutuiu" )
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going with @wjandrea's answer as I've found a way to get my output with just pairs with `=` and separated by spaces.